# two First characters in input unselectable/uneditable and must be 09

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, phone-number

I have an input where the user can enter an phone number (national format) value. The "09" numbers are part of the phone number of the input field so the user only needs to enter the rest of the phone number. I'd like to have the "09" numbers as html and make it unselectable/uneditable. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: You want "09" to be a part of the input value?

Comment: yes, 09 is a part of the input value

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you showed what you tried as well. but not knowing that, will the below work for you?

```
<label for="tel">09</label> <input id="tel" type="number" placeholder="Enter your telphone number">
```

you can also achieve this in bootstrap way as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_input_group&stacked=h)

Comment: "09" is a part of the input value . i want somthing like this solution with JS.      http://jsfiddle.net/QrrjW/1/